# ITFOXTEC SAML2 CORE example will not compile

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am trying to build your sample. I’ve removed all the projects down to the Test Web App Core and have added the latest SAML 2 and SAML 2 MVC packages from NuGet. I am getting a compiler error  (see below). Services.BindConfig does not exist.

Any help would be appreciated.

......

namespace TestWebAppCore
{
public class Startup
{
public static IWebHostEnvironment AppEnvironment { get; private set; }

```
    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        AppEnvironment = env;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        **services.BindConfig**<Saml2Configuration>(Configuration, "Saml2", (serviceProvider, saml2Configuration) =>
        {
```

```
I've downloaded the ITFOXTEC SAML2 example project from github and am trying to get it to work

EDIT: I do have the appropriate package & includes.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4zKu.png
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occur because you are using the wrong SAML 2 MVC package, you need to use the [ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore/) package. And add a using statement for the namespace `ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it. The newest NuGet release is 3/24/22. BindConfig support was added later on 6/1/22. So if you want to use the version that's in NuGet, just select the next oldest version of the test app in GitHub to get the code that doesn't use BindConfig. For the TestWebAppCore Startup.cs file it's https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/d31f7a1b1ff9251810a4fcef8ac2dc920e2a94ef/test/TestWebAppCore/Startup.cs